# tumblr preview renders text styling differently then the actual site

Tags: html, css, text, tumblr

Hey this is extremely frustrating and i can NOT figure it out. I am a novice html/css coder. this problem is specifically with the links and text styling. It appears correct in the theme preview editor... but when i open up my blog directly from its url it is not the same here is what what I have in reference to the problem code.

Please help this is driving me crazy, the url is http://www.ensu3.tumblr.com

the meta for custom options

`

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
   background: {color:Background} url('{image:Background Image}') 
{text:BackgroundProperties};
    }
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    }
 a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
 a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
    }
#logo img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    }
#title {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: {font:Title};
    font-size: {text:HeaderSize};
    color: {color:Title};
    }
#title h1 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    }
#title a:link, #title a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
#title a:hover, #title a:active {
    color: {color:LinksHover};
    }
#title a {
    transition: color .7s;
    -moz-transition: color .7s;
    -webkit-transition: color .7s;
    -o-transition: color .7s;
    }
#nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: {color:Links};
    font-family: {font:Links};
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    }
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    }

<div class="header">
    {block:IfLogoImage}
    <div class="header" id="logo"><a href="/#"><img src="{image:Logo}" /></a></div>
    {/block:IfLogoImage}
    {block:IfNotLogoImage}
           <div class="header" id="title"><h1><a href="/#">{Title}</a></h1>
    {/block:IfNotLogoImage}
</div>
    <div class="header">
        <ul id="nav">
            {block:AskEnabled}
                <li><a href="{/ask}" alt="{AskLabel}">{AskLabel}</a></li>           
            {/block:AskEnabled}
            {block:SubmissionsEnabled}
                        <li><a href="{/submit}" alt="Submit">{SubmitLabel}</a></li>
            {/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
            {block:HasPages}
            {block:Pages}
                        <li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>
            {/block:Pages}
            {/block:HasPages}
                        <li><a href="test link">TestLink</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test link">TextLink2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to hit save?

Also, it can take a while for changes to show up, since Tumblr caches page templates very aggressively.

Comment: Yes I save it every time and it still does not show up the same, Im going to make it in the editor and then upload the static file to tumblr to see if that works... fingers crossed!